# aws iot rule fails with message "Error while evaluating operator '=': Undefined result"

Tags: aws-iot

I created an AWS IOT Rule with the following SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM 'colors' WHERE color = 'green'
```

Then I use the "Test Tool" in the IoT console to publish the following message to the 'colors' topic:

```
{
  "default": "{\"color\":\"green\",\"temperature\":100}"
}
```

The rule does not trigger the configured action, that would be sending the message to a SNS topic.

On cloudwatch logs I see the following error message:

```
[ERROR] EVENT:WhereEval TOPICNAME:colors CLIENTID:iotconsole-1554220753724-0 MESSAGE:Error while evaluating where clause: Undefined result
```

What am I missing? The [AWS IoT SQL documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-sql-operators.html) defines the '=' operator.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found my mistake. The SQL syntax wasn't wrong, what was wrong was the message. I had to change the message to:

```
{
  "default": "{\"color\":\"green\",\"temperature\":200}",
  "color": "green"
}
```

Now the SQL was able to find the 'color' property.

The action to publish on the SNS topic was accomplished and I received the unescaped JSON that was written in the 'message' field:

```
{"color":"green","temperature":200}
```

Comment: Worked only because you added a second color property outside the scope of {default} So now you have to modify both - data redundancy is asking from troubles later on. See my answer below.